# Downloading Gracenote Mobile Client

Tags: gracenote

I have some problems downloading the Mobile Client from developer.gracenote.com.

Am registered and signed in to gracenote's developer program, but I'm unable to download the Mobile Client SDK from https://developer.gracenote.com/mobile-client

When selecting Mobile Client 3.2.0.144 for iOS
https://developer.gracenote.com/system/files/GN_Music_SDK_iOS_3_2_0_144.zip

It brings me to a page showing the following error :

> Access Denied
>
> You are not authorized to access this page.

Am i missing something or do gracenote have a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a temporary misconfiguration on the website - it should be fixed now.

Comment: Is this issue also affecting the "Add new App" button? It is displaying a page reading "No API Products available. Only one API keys per API Product is allowed."

Comment: Not related, but there was a separate change that limits developers to a single API key per API Product. If you already have one API Key, that's why you see that message.